On login set an item using the login url in oracle apex
I need to pass an item as a parameter in the login url and on login the value should be assigned to a page item or application item which is then passed as an argument of a package to be run in prerendering process. And if this parameter is null then I am branching to another page without calling the prerendering process which will be the home page if login url doesn't pass the parameter

There seems to be no question here. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please add enough code (as text) inside the question in order to create a [mre]. If you are receiving any errors, then please add those inside the question (as text) as well

Actually I was stuck in passing a parameter to a page item on page 10, but we solved it by having a hidden item in login page which will hold and pass on the value to page 10. This solved the issue. Thank you
